# Calling extended class function in same arrray Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have two classes LoanBook & STLoanBook, STLoanBook is an extension of LoanBook. These are both inside the same array:

```
private static final LoanBook[] books = new LoanBook[50];
books[0] = new STLoanBook("B129", "Soil Mechanics", "Engineering");
books[1] = new LoanBook("B238", "Basic Biology", "Science");
books[2] = new LoanBook("B563", "Company Law", "Business");
books[3] = new STLoanBook("B342", "Cost Accounting", "Business");
books[4] = new LoanBook("B754", "Robotics", "Engineering");
```

I am trying to call a function reserve() that is only within STLoanBook, when I call it through a for loop, it tells me that reserve() doesn't exist as it is checking LoanBook class. How can I fix this, as I've got the loop already checking the class SimpleName(), but it seems to still error. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` operator and `casting` inside your for loop e.g.

```
    for (LoanBook book : books) {
        if (book instanceof STLoanBook) {
            ((STLoanBook)book).reserve();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by creating a method `reserve()` in LoanBook and extend this method in STLoanBook if it doesn't need to do anything this methode can be :

```
void reverse() {
    return;
}
```

in LoanBook.

Answer (score 0):

You need `instanceof` and a cast:

```
for( book : books ) {
    if( book instanceof STLoanBook ) {
         ((STLoanBook)book).reserve( );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instanceof operator

Sample code:

```
    A[] books = new A[10];
    books[0] = new A();
    books[1] = new B();
    books[2] = new B();
    books[3] = new A();

    for (A a:books) {
        if (a instanceof B) {
            ((B) a).reserve();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the object is an instanceof STLoanBook.
If it is, cast it to STLoanBook then call the reserve function() on it.

```
for (LoanBook book : books) {
    if (book instanceof STLoanBook) {
        ((STLoanBook)book).reserve();
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to write an empty reserve() function for LoanBook and avoid using instanceof, but it doesn't look like you need that.